# How to iterate through string-array in strings.xml outside MainAcitivty

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to access this string array and enumerate the values into a recycler-view however keep getting an string array source not found exception.

```
<string-array name="Entries">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

How would I make this work outside of the MainActivity in kotlin. The example in the documentation doesnt work outside of the mainactivity, so is there a parent class that should be referenced?

```
val array: Array = resources.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)
```

Fragment(list)

```
init {
    Log.i("TAG", "TESTING HERE")
    val array = Resources.getSystem().getStringArray(R.array.Cities)

    for (i in array) {
        Log.i("TAG", i)
    }

    addItem(createPlaceholderItem(1, "text"))

}
```

Comment: You would need the `Context` to get access to the `res`. If you want to do it outside the `MainActivity` pass the context to wherever you want to do it, get the resources and tadaa you have it

Comment: Just to add to that, ``Activity``s implement ``Context``, which is basically an object that gives you access to info and resources in the app and the environment it's running in. So when you access ``resources``, it's really ``this.resources`` where ``this`` is the activity. Because it *is* a ``Context``, you can access ``resources`` on it. But you need access to a ``Context`` to do that, so generally you'll need to pass a ``context`` parameter around (you see this a lot) or access it on something else you have which makes one available (like a ``View``)

Comment: Is there any way to import that Context without having it passed?

Comment: @aeon not really - if you think about it, when you just write some code, it's self-contained. It doesn't know anything about where it's being run or have access to anything external, if it needs access to the wider *context* (get it?) you have to provide it from the outside. In Android, generally speaking, the *stuff* your app runs in (``Activity``s, ``Service``s) gives you access to the context, and you can write things that access those, or have a context passed in through the constructor, or have it provided through a ``setContext`` method or something... hold on let me do an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is in a `Fragment` right?

So a `Fragment` gets attached to an `Activity` the fragment has a `getContext()` method (or you can just reference `context` - Kotlin turns `getX()` functions into readable properties, so it looks like a variable). So you can access `resources` through that.

**But** the thing about Fragments is they're not *always* attached to an Activity. They have different lifecycles, so there are times when a Fragment is detached - one of those is when it's first created, and it's not attached to the Activity yet.

I'm assuming `val array` is a top-level property, i.e. it's being initialised when the Fragment is constructed, meaning when it's not attached and doesn't have access to a context. This is a no-go! And because `Fragment`s are a standard component that the system often creates, you can't adapt it to pass a `Context` in through the constructor or anything.

---

So instead, you can only initialise `array` when you have a `Context`. A typical way to do this is in [`onAttach`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)), which is called when the Fragment is attached to a `FragmentManager`, and it passes the context in as a parameter. This happens very early in the lifecycle, [before `onCreate` is called](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created)

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    // now you have a context, and you can initialise your array
}
```

There's a few ways to initialise it - the simplest is to make `array` nullable:

```
val array: Array? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    array = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)
}
```

but in general this is a bad idea - now that property is nullable, it *might be null* and you have to handle that possibility everywhere. But for something that usually won't be null, and you're only making it nullable so you can delay initialisation, `lateinit` is the better option:

```
lateinit var array: Array

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    array = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)
}
```

`lateinit` is the compiler allowing you to *not* initialise a property with a value, but you're promising to set it **before** anything tries to read it. This is a great fit for a lot of Android stuff where there's a lifecycle, and the "initialisation" stage takes a while - e.g. maybe you can only assign some stuff in an Activity's `onCreate` (instead of at construction), but you know everything that actually uses it will run later.

Another option is `lazy`, which allows you to provide some initialisation code that only runs when the property is first read:

```
val array: Array by lazy {
    requireContext().resources.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)
}
```

The first time that property's read, the code will call `requireContext` (which returns the Fragment's context, or throws an exception if it doesn't have one) and then create the array value. The implication here is that it can *only* be first called when your Fragment has a context - so it's also useful for "stuff that isn't available at construction, but will be when the property is first accessed". Once it has a value, it's stored as a normal `val` - the lambda only runs once.

(Just be careful with this, don't store any `View`s with a `lazy` in a Fragment because a Fragment will sometimes need to recreate its views, but they won't be reassigned to what's basically a set-once `val`. `lateinit`s are always `var` so they can be written over)

---

Basically sometimes you don't have access to this context stuff yet, so you have to defer the actions that use it until you do have it. If you can guarantee things will be initialised before they're used, you have a few options! Otherwise you can use things like `getContext()` (which returns null if you don't have one) and gracefully handle the situations where you don't have access to the thing. (This doesn't just happen with contexts, but you'll run into contexts a lot!)